# Toyota Gaia 3s 4wD .when brake pedal depressed park lamps come on

Tags: toyota, automatic-transmission

As I start my car the dashboard illuminates without turning on the park and head light switch. Also the handbrake warning lamp goes dull/dim but not totally out when I releases the handbrake lever. .I don't know whether these causes the car not to accelerate even in L 2 D,or even in R..a piece of advice is highly appreciate. .

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your question isn't making much sense to me. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if one problem you may have is a loose or poor ground for the dash - there may be one or more wires doing the grounding which you will have to find and check.

You may also have a poor ground or earth at one or both of the rear lamps.